Building Audio-to-image classification And make a best Architecture Model
How to Identified any specific applications or use cases for the audio to image classification model  building?
I tried making Architecture Model Like CNN but It cant predict The image, I expected that the model ability to identity the corresponding image to the Audio but it's hard to achieve after all.
